# capitalization of library class names

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do `collection.defaultdict` and `collection.OrderedDict` have different capitalizations?

Is there some subtle difference that I should be aware of?

(P3K)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The capitalization of the class names is irrelevant, it doesn't signify anything.  Except that Python has sometimes grown organically and the standard library doesn't have the same homogenous feel as other large libraries such as the Win32 API or the Java standard library.

Comment: It should be noted that there _was_ an effort in Python 3, to standardize the names of the builtin modules and classes. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#pep-8-violations-done

Answer (score 2):

Usually, that is in accordance with good style, classes are capitalised.

```
def MyClass (object):
    pass

my_instance = MyClass()
```

like this.

You should read this document about it:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Then the question is, why is this not the case for `defaultdict`?

Comment: Uhm. Good Question. :-) I think it may be to be consistent with its parent class, dict. dict is one of the built in types and, as such, lowercase (str, int, ...). May be the authors wanted to keep open the option to introduce defaultdict to the built in namespace, alongside dict. In which case, **breaking the rules** (cf. PEP8) would make sense.

Comment: `OrderedDict` is also a subclass of `dict`, and it's capitalized properly. As to converting `defaultdict` into a built-in class, why not convert the capitalization at the same time? By that token, any new class in Python libraries should be written in lowercase, in case it might one day become a builtin.

Comment: *singularity* finally explained it properly, makes absolute sense.

Answer (score 1):

defaultdict is written in C and pep8 don't apply , in the other hand OrderDict is written in python,

you can read C code norm for the C implementation of Python here : [PEP 7](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0007/)

reference : source code python2.7

```
defaultdict  : Modules/_collectionsmodule.c
OrderDict : Lib/collections.py
```

Comment: Why can't the C class be exposed to Python library in capitalized case? C is case-sensitive. What am I missing?

Comment: @max: every language has his norm of coding , we can't code in C using python norm pep8 right ? here is the norm for C extention : http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0007/

Comment: I agree in general... but when writing a function in C for the sole purpose of providing a library function for Python's standard library, I'd follow Python style for the function name