# Inconsistent naming convention in python collections module?

Tags: python, collections, naming-conventions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [capitalization of library class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032925/capitalization-of-library-class-names)

Why does the dict subclass `defaultdict` not follow the CapWords naming convention that the other two dict subclasses from the collections module (`Counter`, `OrderedDict`) follow?

PEP 8 recommends the CapWords convention for classes.

Comment: Purely speculative on my part, but this makes `defaultdict()` pretty similar to `dict()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking throughout CPython source I can mention that collection modules consists of two capitalized collection types: OrderedDict and Counter both implemented in **Python** and three other types, where namedtuple is *a function*, deque and defaultdict types are implemented in **C**. So there's a whole difference.