# Why python3 str has startswith and not starts_with?

Tags: python-3.x

Doesn't it seem to be not following the code convention and function naming?

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [capitalization of library class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032925/capitalization-of-library-class-names)

Comment: Not directly a duplicate, but "Why is Python so inconsistent with naming" has been asked multiple times in various forms. It doesn't really have any good answer apart from "mistakes were made".